# Is it possible to use Laravel Socialite and Laravel Cashier in the same application?

Tags: php, laravel-socialite, laravel-cashier

Is it possible to use [Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) and [Laravel Cashier](https://github.com/laravel/cashier) in the same [Laravel 5.1](http://laravel.com/) application?

I have done many searches online and have found no examples of this being done, only others asking if it an be done as well and no answers.

Has anyone done this, know of a project that does this, or simply know if it's possibble to use them together?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Socialite and Laravel Cashier can be used together. Laravel Socialite and Laravel Cashier both relies on the users-table. You shouldnt bump into any issues using both in the same Laravel Application.